# upload files in JIRA via REST API

Tags: json, rest, attachment, jira

We all pretty well know that the request and response format for JIRA REST API are in the form of JSON. I successfully retrieved the attachment details of the uploaded files using the url of type `http://example.com:8080/jira/rest/api/2/attachment`.

I now need to work on file upload on to JIRA using the same REST API. I own a java client and its stated tat I need to post multipart input using `MultiPartEntity`. I do not know how to submit a header of `X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck` with the JSON request. Searching the documents I got only curl based request examples. Can anyone help me fixing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an HTTP header in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819474/how-to-send-an-http-header-in-java)

Comment: I'd start with https://studio.atlassian.com/svn/JRJC/trunk/atlassian-jira-rest-java-client/src/test/java/it/JerseyIssueRestClientTest.java which has a testAddAttachment method

Comment: Thanks Mdoar. But still there is no hint regarding how to post the MultipartEntity.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it this way, and it works:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(args[ 0 ]);
    String fileName = f.getName();
    String url = "https://[JIRA-SERVER]/rest/api/2/issue/[JIRA-KEY]/attachments";

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost( url );
    post.setHeader( "Authorization", basicAuthHeader( "username", "password" ) );
    post.setHeader( "X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck" );
    HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .setMode( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE )
            .addBinaryBody( "file",
                new FileInputStream( f ),
                ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
                f.getName() )
            .build();
    post.setEntity( reqEntity );
    post.setHeader( reqEntity.getContentType() );
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute( post );
}

public static String basicAuthHeader( String user, String pass ) {
    if ( user == null || pass == null ) return null;
    try {
        byte[] bytes = ( user + ":" + pass ).getBytes( "UTF-8" );
        String base64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary( bytes );
        return "Basic " + base64;
    }
    catch ( IOException ioe ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( "Stop the world, Java broken: " + ioe, ioe );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i did it dependencies okhttp and okio

```
private static void upload(File file) throws Exception{
    final String address = "https://domain/rest/api/2/issue/issueId/attachments";
    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    final RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file))
            .build();
    final Request request = new Request.Builder().url(address).post(formBody)
            .addHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic api_token_from_your_account")
            .build();
    final Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.code() + " => " + response.body().string());
}
```