# Post attachment to Jira using REST API in c#

Tags: c#, post, jira

I Have a problem. When I want to POST some attachment to JIRA using REST API i have a Web Exception with 404 code (not found). My method takes CookieContainer to authenticate User. This is my code:

```
 HttpWebResponse response;
        string path = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\nowy.txt";
        var boundary = string.Format("----------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (Cookie c in responseCookies)
            request.CookieContainer.Add(c);
        request.ContentType = String.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck file=@my_file.txt");
        request.Headers.Add("charset", "UTF-8");
        request.KeepAlive = false; 

        var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(fileContent);
        }


        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
```

I used for many support, but any resolved my problem. So do you have some idea?

EDIT 1

now Jira returns 200 code but attachment was not added.. can you tell me what's wrong in my code?

```
public void AddAtachment(CookieCollection responseCookies)
    {
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (Cookie c in responseCookies)
            request.CookieContainer.Add(c);
        Console.Write(request.RequestUri);
        HttpWebResponse response;
        string fileUrl = @"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\nowy.txt";
        var boundary = string.Format("----------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());


        request.ContentType = String.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");

        MemoryStream postDataStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter postDataWriter = new StreamWriter(postDataStream);

        postDataWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        postDataWriter.Write("Content-Disposition: form-data;"
                    + "@file=\"{0}\";"
                    + "filename=\"{1}\""
                    + "\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n",
                    "myFile",
                    Path.GetFileName(fileUrl),
                    Path.GetExtension(fileUrl));
        postDataWriter.Flush();

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            postDataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        fileStream.Close();

        postDataWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        postDataWriter.Flush();

        request.ContentLength = postDataStream.Length;

        using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postDataStream.WriteTo(s);
        }

        postDataStream.Close();

        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string reply = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(reply);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set the request path?

Comment: in constructor i create request: http://baseUrl/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/attachments

Comment: Have you done it manually with Fiddler (or something like it)?  One issue I've seen with this is that the encodings don't match between what you stream and what you told it you were streaming.

Comment: so if I use fiddler in textview panel i see only System.Byte[] not my text in file.. what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How to POST attachment to JIRA using REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886316/how-to-post-attachment-to-jira-using-rest-api/18489214#18489214).

From what I can see, your problem is in the Content-Disposition header. [RFC-1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt) expects the form-data name to be **"file"** and nothing else. For more details, look at the post on Atlassian Forums: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/104822/jira-rest-api-attachment-incoherent-result.

You may take a look at my answer provided on the Duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489214/424059